# SQL Query to format output

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a element of my SQL Query which is outputting a date,

Query Element

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), UPOST, 100)) AS UPDATED
```

Output

```
2013-05-03 00:00:00.000
```

What I need to do is get rid of the zeros and change the format so that it reads like this;

```
03-05-2013
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this

Comment: Any reason you can't return the `DATETIME` and format client side?

Comment: SQL Server **2008** and newer has `DATE` - you can convert your `DATETIME` to `DATE` first so it "loses" the time portion. SQL Server **2012** and newer have a function called `FORMAT` (like `string.Format` in C#) that allows detailed specification of your output format

Comment: Yeah the application that is handling the data is not able to format the output, and I am unable to effect change there, bummer I know but thats what I have to work with

Comment: `DATE` applied so zero's dealt with thanks @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(113), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), UPOST, 100)), 105) AS UPDATED
```

the final 105 means that the format will be dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

We have something like this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_StripTime(@DT datetime)
 RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   return convert(datetime, convert(nvarchar,@DT,112))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `110` instead of `100`

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS UPDATED
```

`110` will format the date as `MM-DD-YYYY`

And, for future reference, bookmark this page: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx